# Fix Blender's script to link two mesh objects and keep the UV mapping each one has

Tags: mesh, scripting

I want to link two mesh objects and keep the UV mapping each one has and I've found solution [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14590/can-you-link-two-mesh-objects-and-keep-the-uv-mapping-each-one-has), but for me script doesn't work. I'm getting error:

> AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "link" not found

in 30 line. I've found information about replacing collection system in Blender 2.8 but I don't know how to use that information. I'm using Blender 4.0.2. How can I fix this script?

Full script:

```
# make sure to be in Object mode
# make sure to have two objects selected
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from contextlib import ExitStack

def work():
    C = bpy.context
    if C.mode != 'OBJECT':
        return
    if len(C.selected_objects) < 1:
        print("Must have at least one object selected")
        return
    # read into bmesh safely
    names = []
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        bm = bmesh.new()
        stack.callback(bm.free)
        for o in C.selected_objects:
            if o.type != 'MESH':
                continue
            m = o.matrix_world
            bm.transform(m.inverted())
            bm.from_mesh(o.data)
            bm.transform(m)
            names.append(o.name)
        # write to actual mesh
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Result')
        object = bpy.data.objects.new('Merge(%s)' % ', '.join(names), mesh)
        bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    C.scene.objects.link(object)
    C.scene.update()

work()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These points have been changed with Blender 2.8

line 32: [see here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145658/link-new-object-to-scene-with-python-in-2-8)

```
old: context.scene.objects.link(object)
new: context.collection.objects.link(object)
```

line 33: [see here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140789/what-is-the-replacement-for-scene-update)

```
old: context.scene.update()
new: context.view_layer.update()
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this one, but are you sure it's right option? In my case merge's result doesn't have any materials. Maybe, there is error in original script - in that case your answer is right.